# How to reinstall macOS?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have only Ubuntu 16.04 (no Partitions) running on my MacBook (My model is A1181) but I would like to install macOS, replacing Ubuntu. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help if you can specify the model of your MacBook and the macOS release that you wish to install.

Comment: Any OS version that can run on this model

Comment: @NimeshNeema My fault. I removed the model. I did not think that it was relevant.

Comment: Could you include information about the processor? Use the System Monitor as described in the accepted answer to the question: [Getting Processor Information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26393/getting-processor-information). Also, can you include the size of the internal drive? Is the case black or white? Also, have you considered running Windows 10 on your Mac? Does your DVD (optical) drive work?

Answer (score 2):

Boot your Mac holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd> keys. This should get you into [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314).

First get into disk Utility and delete the Ubuntu partition and format it as macOS Journaled HFS+. Once that is done quit out of disk utility and click on Reinstall MacOS.

It will connect to your network via WiFi (so if you can do ethernet, it will go faster) asking you for your WiFi password and proceed to install the version of macOS that your Mac came with.

Once macOS is installed you can log into the mac and then into the App Store and pick a later version of macOS that you want on your Mac if the one that was installed is not as up to date as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X Lion is the last supported release for your MacBook. To get started, you will need to obtain a copy of Mac OS X Lion if you don't have it already. You can order one [here](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion). Or you can obtain a USB key with the Mac OS X installer pre-loaded.

You can follow the instructions in the Apple support document, [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372) to create a bootable USB key installer. (You'll need a working Mac to do so)

Now, assuming you have bootable key ready, restart your MacBook and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> key. Select the USB drive as the startup disk. Now you can follow the on-screen instructions to wipe the internal drive and install Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: The A1181 is the model name for the MacBook "Core Duo" 1.83 13" MacBook1,1 (max: 10.6.8) up to MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.13 13" (White-09) MacBook5,2 (max: 10.11.6)! I don't know where you've found Lion as last supported release - an already deleted comment?

Comment: @klanomath [This](https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility) article.